# Measuring byte count downloaded via twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

I want to measure the number of bytes downloaded by twitter4j when doing various operations. Is there an easy way to do that or am I going to need to modify the sources?

For example, when I do this:

```
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline();
```

I want to find out that it downloaded 28,757 (I made that number up in this case, but it does match the result from doing the equivalent using `curl`).

**UPDATE**: after digging into the code a little bit, it looks like I may have to re-implement `TwitterImpl.get()` and `TwitterImpl.post()` to get what I want.